# Vote count on reputation tab

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-count, reputation-history

The vote count displayed in the reputation tab is wrong if the answer gets accepted. The acceptance of the answer counts as a vote.

That might be by-design, but I think it's confusing.

For example it lists:

> +75    1 hour ago     7 votes  C# - Static readonly strings — possible to run into multithread issues?

But that answer is `+6|-0`. It's the same for all my accepted answers.

Comment: I am not positive about this, but certainly seems this is by-design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct in the "by post view", it is an "accept vote" that happens, and making that particular thing any clearer would cost some valuable real-estate.

However there was room for improvement, if you got a bounty or accept on that post, we'll give it some nice styling to quickly indicate that, [you can now see this styling ion your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445517/codeinchaos?tab=reputation&startDate=2011-06-16).

If the answer was awarded a **bounty** or **accepted answer** (bounty wins in a fight), you'll see this styling:

[image]

Comment: you just wanted to show off the +970, didn't you ;)

Comment: @yoda - I've only won a few bounties ever, it was the easiest to find in the rep list