# Odd wording when viewing rep by post

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vote count on reputation tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95419/vote-count-on-reputation-tab)

If I go to a user's page, click the "reputation" tab, and choose the "by post" filter, I see something like this:

[image: 2 votes vs 1 vote]
[Note: This is just an example from my page, but it's repeatable on other user pages]

It just seems odd that the summary for today says "2 votes", but broken out it's 1 vote and 1 accept.  Granted I can't think of a good alternative ("2 events", "2 Items"?), I just thought I'd bring it up on here to see what people thought.

This is kind of a nit-picky thing, so I'm not sure if it's important.

Comment: I've often wondered that myself

Comment: "2 rep changes" :)

Comment: Is there anything semantically wrong with considering that an accept is a vote by the question owner?

Comment: Technically accepts are a type of vote internally, not that we generally think of it that way. Unless somebody comes up with a good word, I'd rather keep it "votes" -- "events"/"items"/"responses" are all pretty bad

Comment: @Michael I feel weird about accepts being a type of vote; it implies someone other than the OP has a say in the matter (like voting to close).  They can accept whatever answer they want, regardless of votes.  I agree that (so far) "votes" is still much better than the alternatives =)

Comment: If you look at the [Unanswered](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered) page, you will see that questions with an accepted answer are not listed, for the fact that accepting an answer is considered a kind of vote.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I would think questions with an accepted answer don't show up on the *unanswered* page because they *do have an answer*, right?  Or am I missing something there?

Comment: That page lists questions with no up voted answers, as stated in the page itself.

Comment: @Kiamlaluno Apologies, I see what you're saying now.  That's a very good point.

Comment: @PopularDemand @ NickCraver Sorry for the dupe!  Thanks for finding that =)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps "2 responses" would be more accurate without being as vague as "items"?

Comment: ***Definitely*** better than my ideas, but still sounds off to me.

Comment: A *response* is something different in my opinion...*reactions* comes closer...

Answer (score -1):

I belive this has been asked somewhere before.

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

An accepted answer is considered a `vote`

Comment: Indeed it has (been asked before).

Comment: I was thinking that it must have been asked and answered, but my search-fu has failed me so far.